# How To Summarize in HH:MM:SS of call duration

Tags: formula, formula-field

I have to summarize call duration(Seconds). I created a custom field named Call Duration Hours.

```
IF((MOD(CallDurationInSeconds/60,1)*60) > 10, 
VALUE(TEXT(FLOOR( CallDurationInSeconds/60)) + "." + TEXT(FLOOR(MOD( CallDurationInSeconds/60,1)*60) )), 
VALUE(TEXT(FLOOR( CallDurationInSeconds/60)) + ".0" + TEXT(FLOOR(MOD( CallDurationInSeconds/60,1)*60) )) 
)
```

Now I am able to summarize but it's showing everything in minutes like for example if the duration is 1 hour 50 minutes, it's showing 110. I want to display in format like HH:MM:SS.

I am getting in text format with the below rule.I am trying convert it to number using **value** Function.It display **!Error** in field value.

```
IF( 
ISBLANK(CallDurationInSeconds),"", 
TEXT(FLOOR(CallDurationInSeconds/3600)) + ":" + TEXT( FLOOR(MOD(CallDurationInSeconds,3600)/60)) + ":" + TEXT(MOD(MOD(CallDurationInSeconds,3600),60)))
```

But,I want it in number format.Is there any way to get in number format

For reference:

[image: My reporting screenshot]

Comment: 1h50m is only 110 minutes so if it is showing 150 it is wrong to start with or you are wrong on the duration.

Comment: Hey @Eric sorry i unfortunately wrongly updated my question.ow i am updated my question.For example 1 13 minutes it's showing 73 miutes

Comment: Hey @Adrian Larson i am updated my question with perfect criteria.

Comment: Your example format is not in a numeric format - it is displaying as HH:MM:SS which can only really be done in a formula field with return type of Text. All the other formula return types cannot support that format.

Comment: Thanks @DaveHumm But is there any workarounds. Because i want to calculate total talk time of a user through reporting itself.